# Sketch effect logo in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

[image]

I have a problem. I want to create this kind of logo in Illustrator but I'm stuck on how this effect can be achieved.

Comment: You could simply draw it by hand.  Might be easier if you have a graphics tablet and stylus, but entirely possible even with a mouse. Just use the Pencil Tool.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think you're right, it's drawn manually.

Comment: Oh wait, I just saw a Dansky tutorial, it can be done with scribble effect @BillyKerr

Comment: @Vikas Sure, brushes or the pencil tool.  Either way.

Comment: @BillyKerr I typed wrong  edited my comment  But yes sure, nothing matches manually done effects.

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm thinking to write an answer about manually done. Are you also thinking? If yes I'll ignore. Just wanted to make sure either one of us don't waste time. I'll try if result looks nice, I'll post. Else I'll ignore.

Comment: @Vikas I'd say in this case it's not the scribble effect, but yes it is possible, however tweaking the scribble settings to get it to look just right might take longer than just drawing it by hand.  Sure I think an answer showing a manual effect would be great. Go ahead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*That* image appears to possibly be manually manipulated. However, you can approximate the general appearance with the **Scribble Effect** in Illustrator

Fill a shape with a color and choose `Effect > Stylize > Scribble` and adjust the settings.

Expand and alter further if desired.

Answer (score 8):

If you are good at drawing with mouse or you have a drawing pad, you may want to consider the following manual approach. This way, it can also be quite unique.

I don't have any drawing pad/pen so I used my mouse, so corners look a bit sharp and perhaps not exactly what you want. But I feel if you have better tools and you invest more time, you can design a pretty nice one.

I used pen tool and drawn a few paths using pencil tool as shown in the GIF *(GIF is of low quality as file size was very big)*. (Place a shape layer or outlines of your logo structure in bottom and lock it so you know where to draw).

Then I changed stroke width to 5 or 6 pts. Adjusted some path smoothness settings using Simplify tool. Select all artwork and then open `Object > Path > Simplify`. You can simplify more than once for more refinement, if it works.

[image]

Finally you can change the stroke corners and ends to Rounded ones.

[image]

Once you're satisfied with result, expand it and use it.

[image]

Comment: You totally nailed that. You got +1 from me!

Comment: @BillyKerr thank you for encouraging me.

Comment: Very nice answer.